# Request Post in GAE Method Request Post in GAE

Tags: forms, google-app-engine, post, request

I wonder if there is a way to make a request for a form which was sent by post in a way more dynamic without having to be variable by setting the variable. I mean if I have a form with 10 fields instead of doing:

```
var1 = self.request ('text1')
[...]
var10 self.request = ('text10')
```

If there is any way that he has returned me a list where the list argument is the field name and the value of the argument is the field value, eg:

```
list = { 'text1': value_text1, [ ... ] }
```

Tanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about the `get_all()` function. For more details [see this reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get_all)